# Proving $(\lambda_1 + \lambda_2)C=\lambda_1 C + \lambda_2 C$ for convex $C$

Tags: proof-verification, convex-analysis

I'd like to know if my proof is okay.

Prove, using the following definitions,

$\lambda C = \lbrace \lambda x \ | \ x \in C\rbrace$

$C+D=\lbrace x+y \ | \ x \in C, y \in D \rbrace $, that

$C$ convex $\implies (\lambda_1 + \lambda_2)C=\lambda_1C+\lambda_2C$ for $\lambda_{1,2}>0$.

My proof:

Suppose $C$ convex, i.e. $\forall x,y\in C \ \forall \lambda\in[0,1] :\lambda x+ (1-\lambda)y\in C$, and let $\lambda_{1,2}\in(0,\infty)$. We have that
$(\lambda_1 + \lambda_2)C=\lbrace (\lambda_1 + \lambda_2) x \ | \ x \in C\rbrace$, and we want to show that $(\lambda_1 + \lambda_2)C=\lbrace x+y \ | \ x \in \lambda_1C, y \in \lambda_2 C \rbrace $.

(1) First, take an element $d\in(\lambda_1 + \lambda_2)C$, then $d=\lambda_1 x + \lambda_2 x$ for some $x\in C$ and thus $(\lambda_1 + \lambda_2)C\subseteq \lambda_1C+\lambda_2C$.

(2) Now, we show that $(\lambda_1 + \lambda_2)x=\lambda_1 c_1+\lambda_2 c_2, \ c_{1,2}\in C,$ always has a solution $\bar{x}\in C.$

Take $\bar{x}=\frac{\lambda_1}{\lambda_1+\lambda_2}c_1 + \frac{\lambda_2}{\lambda_1+\lambda_2}c_2$, then $\bar{x}$ is a convex combination of points in $C$, and thus in $C$, and therefore $(\lambda_1 + \lambda_2)C \supseteq \lambda_1C+\lambda_2C$.

Combining (1) and (2) gives $(\lambda_1 + \lambda_2)C=\lambda_1C+\lambda_2C$ and we are done.

Comment: You are proving $(\lambda_1 + \lambda_2)C \supseteq \lambda_1C + \lambda_2C$. You need to prove the reverse inclusion as well - that is trivial of course. Remember that in the definition of convex set you can take $\lambda = 0$ or $1$.

Comment: Thanks, I edited the proof.

Comment: I might not have enough coffee yet, but I'm not seeing what convexity has to do with this. That is, $(\lambda_1 + \lambda_2)C = \lambda_1 C + \lambda_2 C$ whether or not $C$ is convex.

Comment: Try $\lbrace (1,1), (1,2) \rbrace$ and you'll see the difference

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The proof is correct, and is a typical proof of this fact. I'll add a remark that the converse is also true: if a set $C$ satisfies the equality $$(\lambda_1 + \lambda_2)C =  \lambda_1 C + \lambda_2 C\tag1$$ for all $\lambda_{1,2}>0$, then it is convex. Indeed, for any $x,y\in C$ and $t\in (0,1)$ the property (1) implies
$$tx+(1-t)y \in tC+(1-t)C = (t+1-t)C=C$$
hence $C$ is convex.